How to deploy and use a nodejs api in a vuejs app on cpanel hosting
I used vite to build my vuejs application for production, but it works with a nodejs api offline. I'm not entirely sure how to run the same "node command", while on a live server that allows the vue app communicate and use the node js api.
I've tried several solutions, which i've seen on stackoverflow, one of which include writing the code below in your "app.js" file, before building it and apparently vuejs would take care of the rest, but it did not work.
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname,"../public/dist/static/")));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../public/dist/') });
});

